# replace relative links in a css with a custom path and a rexep

Tags: javascript, css, regex

With this function I get all relative links in a ajax loaded css file and replace them with a custom path.

```
var newCss = cssText.replace(/url\('([^)]+)'\)/gm, function (a, b) {
    return 'url(\'' + 'myCustomPath' + b + '\')';
});
```

But this one seems to change only links with a *single quote*.

How can I use it also with *double quotes* and *no quotes*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
/url\('([^)]+)'\)/gm
```

by this :

```
/url\(['"]?([^'")]+)['"]?\)/gm
```

Comment: perfect! but why i get a %22 at the end of the final string?